# Java replaceAll puts "null" inside result

Tags: android, regex, replaceall

I have a regex:

```
((((first_url)|(second_url)|(third_url))+\.dom\.local)?|.*)[^.]
```

which should check if my baseURL is local or not.

If I run this inside an regex tester site (like regex 101) I get right result, I mean if I substitute with "$2" I get no results if I don't have one of my local baseURL inside the string.

But in Java I get:

```
String t1 = "first_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(Constants.REGEX_CHECK_GET_URL_LOCAL, "$2").replaceAll("null", "");
String tt1 = "first_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(Constants.REGEX_CHECK_GET_URL_LOCAL, "$2");
String t2 = "another_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(Constants.REGEX_CHECK_GET_URL_LOCAL, "$2").replaceAll("null", "");
String tt2 = "another_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(Constants.REGEX_CHECK_GET_URL_LOCAL, "$2");
```

Where:

```
t1 = "first_url.dom.local"
tt1 = "first_url.dom.localnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull"
t2 = ""
tt2 = "nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull"
```

Why "replaceAll" put all this "null" inside the string?
I solved by replacing again the "nulls", but personally I think is a bad way to solve that.
Also if I try online "replaceAll" I get right result without "null" strings :/

Using "Pattern" and "Matcher" variables doesn't change the result.

Another example:
I have an object property which is an url to the avatar. This property can have the BaseURL to download the avar or can have the relative URL without the BaseURL.

My regex is:

```
((www)\.(.*.)\.((it)|(com)|(org)))?.*.
```

with replace:

```
$1
```

So this should extract only the BaseURL if present (as I tryed on online simulator); instead if I have a string without the BaseURL it extract "null" string instead of empty string "".

Comment: Can you should how you defined REGEX_CHECK_GET_URL_LOCAL?

Comment: It would really help if you could show all of this in a [mcve] so we can copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: Use only a required regex for a simple replace `((((first_url)|(second_url)|(third_url))+\.dom\.local)?)` which group will never be null. And then there is look-behind to check that no dot follows or such.

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to double the backslashes when you converted the regex to Java?

Comment: What is  the Java version? It seems to work well, see https://ideone.com/770yxk

Comment: @sp00m the constant is the regex above:
((((first_url)|(second_url)|(third_url))+\.dom\.local)?|.*)[^.]

Comment: @RealSkeptic they are double on java class

Comment: @Joop Eggen so I can't use complex regex? I never saw this behavior before and I always use regex

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew jdk11, I'm using it on Android. I already tryed on online simulator and works on online simulator without giving "null" inside the result string.

Comment: Yeah, I heard of it on Android. It's engine is a bit different one than Java's.

Comment: @Z3R0 my understanding is that `$1` of `(...)?` could give a null, whereas `((...)?)` would give an empty string in the larger $1. The same principle with alternatives `((...)|...)`

Comment: @Joop Eggen so How can I tell to don't return the "null" value if there isn't the string? Because I'm not sure there will be the string I'm searching in capturing group, so I used quantifier ?.
Also why online tester return empty string and on android I get "null" inside string?
Can I only replace the "null" on resulting string? :/

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew first time I see this :/ looks like a big s**t

Comment: @Z3R0 Place the entire `X?` into its own `(X?)` - then on not finding X (null), you find the empty string ("").

Comment: @JoopEggen It will only work in patterns that have no alternation. In general, in Python 3.4 and older, the common workaround was to use a lambda expression (a callable) as the replacement argument, where one could check if group value is not null. Here, it can be done with `Matcher#appendReplacement`

Comment: @Joop Eggen  If I put "(X?)" it will also match if there isn't the entire string inside the first capture group; but I need all the string inside the first capture group, so that the first capturing group is formed of all the sub-capturing group

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew since java 9 also java has that goodie. The regex seems too ?-ish. With a lambda one could do some of the restrictive matching oneself, for instance maintaining a set of words.

Comment: Last attempt: `(www\.([^/]+)\.(\\w+)).*.`; $1 the root URL, $2 the host, $3 the domain.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I tryed "Matcher#appendReplacement" but it let me put a replace for the resulting string buffering it in first argument. I mean I can add a string like "lol$1lol" for the result of the match, but I didn't find a way to do a replacement like: replace "null" with "".
Actually I'm using an utility method to do all the regex with a "null" replacement hoping that I'll never get a string with a "null" inside lol Like "www.nullable.null.com/nullService/nullArgs"; this will be armageddon 4 me x_x (not true, it will match good xD but if 'll need to extract baseurl it will be replacd)

Comment: In Java, there is `Objects.toString(matcher.group(1), "")` (just `import java.util.Objects;`)

Answer (score 0):

We need more details as your error is not reproductible. As this test works perfectly:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ReplaceRegex {

    @Test
    void checkRegExp() {
        String regex = "((((first_url)|(second_url)|(third_url))+\\.dom\\.local)?|.*)[^.]";
        String t1 = "first_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(regex, "$2").replaceAll("null", "");
        String tt1 = "first_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(regex, "$2");
        String t2 = "another_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(regex, "$2").replaceAll("null", "");
        String tt2 = "another_url.dom.local/service/myService".replaceAll(regex, "$2");

        assertThat(t1).isEqualTo("first_url.dom.local");
        assertThat(t1).isEqualTo(tt1);
        assertThat(t2).isEqualTo("");
        assertThat(t2).isEqualTo(tt2);
    }
}
```

passes as green on Open JDK12.

Are you sure your imported constant is the right one ?

Comment: the jdk is JDK11

Comment: and does my code run on your project in a test class ?

Comment: Not tested and I'm not using jupiter :/ 
Anyway if it isn't working when I run the application using the debugger I think it won't works too. 
I think the answer is on comments in the post above :/ Anyway I'm using Java inside Android environment